# Java: How to avoid multiple selection in radio button..

Tags: java, netbeans

How to avoid multiple selection in radio button.. Here is two radio buttons (jRadioButton1 & jRadioButton2). In the executed window it is possible to select both radio buttons.. how can restrict the number of selection of radio button to  one at a time..

```
if(jRadioButton1.isSelected())
    {
    String radioText = jRadioButton1.getText();
    System.out.println(radioText);
    }
    if(jRadioButton2.isSelected())
    {
    String radioText = jRadioButton2.getText();``
    System.out.println(radioText);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may create a ButtonGroup object and add your JRadioButton objects there.

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(jRadioButton1);
group.add(jRadioButton2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so what you want to do is add all those button to the same button group, only one button from any given button group can be selected at any given time.

```
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;   
     private void groupButton( ) {

        ButtonGroup bg1 = new ButtonGroup( );

        bg1.add(jRadioButton1);
        bg1.add(jRadioButton2);
        bg1.add(jRadioButton3);

        }
```